# Folding a parameter pack of N types into N-1 pairs

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I am trying to fold a parameter pack of `N` different types into a `std::tuple` of `N-1` `std::pairs` with respective types.

So for example the expression

```
ResolveToTupleOfPairs<void, int, long>::Type tuple;
```

should evaluate to

```
std::tuple<std::pair<void, int>, std::pair<int, long>> tuple;
```

So I am searching for an implementation of the `ResolveToTupleOfPairs` type to fold the parameter pack as explained. My current implementation follows, but obviously it causes the type to be a tuple of pairs which each hold the same type twice instead of `<T0, T1>, <T1, T2>, ...`.

```
template<typename... T>
struct ResolveToTupleOfPairs {
    static_assert(sizeof...(Args) > 1, "need at least two arguments");

    using Type = std::tuple<std::pair<T, T>...>;
};
```

I'm fine with `c++17` solutions.

Comment: `void` in a `std::pair`?

Comment: @max66 Just an example type to illustrate my example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We take advantage of the fact that parameter pack expansion is really really smart

```
template<typename...>
struct fold;

template<size_t... Is, typename... Ts>
struct fold<std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts...>
{
    using tuple = std::tuple<Ts...>;
    using type = std::tuple<std::pair<std::tuple_element_t<Is, tuple>,
                                      std::tuple_element_t<Is + 1, tuple>>...>;
};

template<typename... Ts>
using fold_t = typename fold<std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts) - 1>, Ts...>::type;
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/g/QiswDc)

Comment: great use of `std_tuple_element`; I was working on a solution but you answer is far better.

Comment: @Passer Thanks for this superior solution, please see [this followup question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48967213)