# Recursively folding a parameter pack to resolve placeholder types

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, c++17

### Notice: Followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48965685)

After asking [this question about parameter pack folding into pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48965685), I noticed that I need to retain the complete type of the previously folded type as the left pair type.

For example:

```
Fold<char, int, long, double> f;
```

must evaluate to

```
std::tuple<
    std::pair<char
             , int>,
    std::pair<std::pair<char, int> /* <-- the previous resulting type */
             , long>,
    std::pair<std::pair<std::pair<char, int>, long> /* the previous type again */
             , double>
> f;
```

### Context to this problem

The reason why I need this, is because the types which have to be "folded" can be placeholder types. The placeholders "real" type can only be known when both having the fully expanded type to the left as well as the unexpanded type. 
The leftmost type never contains placeholders.

Let me illustrate this with a quick example:

```
struct CopyTypeFromPreviousArgumentTag { };

template<typename T = CopyTypeFromPreviousArgumentTag>
struct Foo;

template<typename T...>
struct Bar {
    /* Here fold will not use std::pair, but a resolver type that takes both A and B and gives back the resolved B */
    Fold<T...> expanded;
};
```

Now `Bar` can be used like this:

```
Bar< Foo<int>
   , Foo<>
   , Foo<>
   , Foo<double>
   , Foo<>
   > f;
```

and the internal type `decltype(f::expanded)` will be:

```
std::tuple< Foo<int>
          , Foo<int>
          , Foo<int>
          , Foo<double>
          , Foo<double>
          >;
```

**EDIT:** The `Bar` class is actually not restricted to any class type it might hold. It can be a mixture of several types. So see the `Foo` class as a placeholder for some type `Foo` where a resolver type traits exists given the previous resolved type: `ResolveType<PreviouslyResolvedType, CurrentType>::Type` will give the resolved type correctly. Hence the `std::pair` idiom.

### My current attempt

I tried to implement the recursion by building upon the answer from the linked question, but can't get it to work.

```
namespace Detail {

template<typename, typename...>
struct Fold;

template
    < size_t... Indices
    , typename... Types
> struct Fold<std::index_sequence<Indices...>, Types...> {
    using Tuple = std::tuple<Types...>;
    using Type = std::tuple<std::pair /* use std::pair just to match the first example */
        //< std::tuple_element_t<Indices, Tuple>
        < typename Fold
            < std::tuple_element_t<Indices, Tuple>
            , std::make_index_sequence<Indices>
            , Types...>::Type; /* Tuple can't be expanded :( */
        , std::tuple_element_t<Indices + 1, Tuple>
        >::Type...>;
};

} /* namespace Detail */


template<typename... Types>
using Fold = typename Detail::Fold<std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Types) - 1>, Types...>::Type;
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand: from `Bar<Foo<int>, Foo<>, Foo<>, Foo<double>, Foo<>> f;` do you want obtain a `type` `std::tuple< Foo<int>, Foo<int>, Foo<int>, Foo<double>, Foo<double>>;`? And what about `std::pair`s? Another question: all types that you want to fold are of type `Foo<something>`?

Comment: Can you extend your follow-up example to four types?

Comment: @NirFriedman I have edited the question to include the extended example using four types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I start my solution by building something that knows how to create the nth type. It's just a pair of the previous created type, and the current source type, so:

```
template <std::size_t I, class T>
struct element {
  using type = std::pair<typename element<I - 1, T>::type,
                         std::tuple_element_t<I + 1, T>>;
};

template <class T>
struct element<0, T> {
  using type =
      std::pair<std::tuple_element_t<0, T>, std::tuple_element_t<1, T>>;
};
```

All we really need to do now is put the input types into a tuple, grab an integer pack, and feed the tuple and unfold the integer pack through `element`, into a new tuple. No problem:

```
template <class I, class... Ts>
class fold_helper;

template <std::size_t... Is, class... Ts>
class fold_helper<std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts...> {

  using tup = std::tuple<Ts...>;

public:
  using type = std::tuple<typename element<Is, tup>::type...>;
};

template <class... Ts>
using Fold = typename fold_helper<std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)-1>,
                                  Ts...>::type;
```

Finally, let's check this works:

```
int main() {

  static_assert(
      std::is_same<Fold<char, int, long, double>,
                   std::tuple<std::pair<char, int>, //
                              std::pair<std::pair<char, int>, long>,
                              std::pair<std::pair<std::pair<char, int>, long>,
                                        double>>>::value,
      "");

  return 0;
};
```

This program compiled for me.

Answer (score 4):

The linked question is a very convoluted way of doing this. If it was a runtime problem, it will obviously be solved with a one-pass algorithm, metaprogramming is no different.

```
struct copy_prev {};

template<typename T = copy_prev>
struct Foo {};

template<typename... Ts, typename T>
auto operator+(std::tuple<Ts...>, Foo<T>)
    -> std::tuple<Ts..., Foo<T>>;

template<typename... Ts>
auto operator+(std::tuple<Ts...> t, Foo<copy_prev>)
    -> std::tuple<Ts..., select_last_t<Ts...>>;

template<typename... Ts>
using fold_t = decltype((std::tuple<>{} + ... + std::declval<Ts>()));
```

Where [`select_last_t`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46560993/4832499) is implemented as

```
template<typename T>
struct tag
{
    using type = T;
};

template<typename... Ts>
struct select_last
{
    using type = typename decltype((tag<Ts>{}, ...))::type;
};

template<typename... Ts>
using select_last_t = typename select_last<Ts...>::type;
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/g/hoCesk)

Comment: Again, thanks for the great answer. Maybe I oversimplified the problem, but the `Foo` class can actually be any class with any amount of template parameters. This is the reason why I wanted to use a type trait like `ResolveType<Previous, Current>::Type` to resolve the type. Can this be adopted in a similar scheme?

Comment: I had never thought to use comma to detect the last type in a list. Great. But is really necessary the use of `tag`? I mean... what about `template <typename ... Ts> struct lastType { using type = std::remove_reference_t<decltype((std::declval<Ts>(),...))>; };`?

Comment: @max66 You'd run into a few issues, first is decaying and references, which can be undesirable in typelists, mentioned in Yakk's answer . Then is the problem of overloaded comma operators. Having a tag type just makes it all nicer.

Comment: @nyronium Use SFINAE and overload `operator+` to get practically any functionality you want. And yes if you can't generalize from an answer to your question, you are oversimplifying

Comment: @PasserBy - you're right: to use `std::declval` ins't a good idea 'cause the risk of an overloaded comma operator. I didn't think about it.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure to understand what do you want... but if your `Bar` struct accept only `Foo` types... that is: if can be written as follows

```
template <typename ...>
struct Bar;

template <typename ...Ts>
struct Bar<Foo<Ts>...>
 { /* something */ };
```

and in `Bar` you want a type so that from

```
 Bar<Foo<int>, Foo<>, Foo<>, Foo<double>, Foo<>>
```

you want the internal type

```
 std::tuple<Foo<int>, Foo<int>, Foo<int>, Foo<double>, Foo<double>>
```

where the unexpressed (defaulted) argument for `Foo` are substituted with the last expressed argument... I don't see an elegant solution.

The best I can imagine is the development of a type helper as follows (where, for the sake of brevity, I've renamed `ctfpat` the former `CopyTypeFromPreviousArgumentTag`)

```
template <typename...>
struct fooFolder;

// error case: the first type of Bar is ctfpat (non impemented;
// generate compile time error)
template <typename ... Ts>
struct fooFolder<std::tuple<>, ctfpat, ctfpat, Ts...>;

template <typename ... Tps, typename Tprev, typename T0, typename ... Ts>
struct fooFolder<std::tuple<Tps...>, Tprev, T0, Ts...>
   : fooFolder<std::tuple<Tps..., Foo<T0>>, T0, Ts...>
 { };

template <typename ... Tps, typename Tprev, typename ... Ts>
struct fooFolder<std::tuple<Tps...>, Tprev, ctfpat, Ts...>
   : fooFolder<std::tuple<Tps..., Foo<Tprev>>, Tprev, Ts...>
 { };

template <typename Tpl, typename Tprev>
struct fooFolder<Tpl, Tprev>
 { using type = Tpl; };
```

and `Bar` become

```
template <typename ...>
struct Bar;

template <typename ...Ts>
struct Bar<Foo<Ts>...>
 {
   using foldedType = typename fooFolder<std::tuple<>, ctfpat, Ts...>::type;

   foldedType expanded;
 };
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

struct ctfpat // copy type from previous argument tag
 { };

template <typename T = ctfpat>
struct Foo
 { };

template <typename ...>
struct fooFolder;

// error case: the first type of Bar is ctfpat (non impemented;
// generate compile time error)
template <typename ... Ts>
struct fooFolder<std::tuple<>, ctfpat, ctfpat, Ts...>;

template <typename ... Tps, typename Tprev, typename T0, typename ... Ts>
struct fooFolder<std::tuple<Tps...>, Tprev, T0, Ts...>
   : fooFolder<std::tuple<Tps..., Foo<T0>>, T0, Ts...>
 { };

template <typename ... Tps, typename Tprev, typename ... Ts>
struct fooFolder<std::tuple<Tps...>, Tprev, ctfpat, Ts...>
   : fooFolder<std::tuple<Tps..., Foo<Tprev>>, Tprev, Ts...>
 { };

template <typename Tpl, typename Tprev>
struct fooFolder<Tpl, Tprev>
 { using type = Tpl; };

template <typename ...>
struct Bar;

template <typename ... Ts>
struct Bar<Foo<Ts>...>
 {
   using foldedType = typename fooFolder<std::tuple<>, ctfpat, Ts...>::type;

   foldedType expanded;
 };

int main()
 {
   using t1 = typename Bar<Foo<>, Foo<int>, Foo<>, Foo<double>,
                           Foo<>>::foldedType;
   using t2 = std::tuple<Foo<int>, Foo<int>, Foo<int>, Foo<double>,
                         Foo<double>>;

   static_assert( std::is_same<t1, t2>{}, "!" );
 }
```

Comment: I apologize if I have oversimplified my problem. See my edited question please.